# A package can not be installed given the up-to-date R version

Tags: r

I tried many times to install the package `data4paprbag` but I did not succeed. I am getting the error message:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘paprbag’ is not available for package ‘data4paprbag’.In addition: Warning message:In is.na(remote_deps$package) :is.na() applied to non-(list or   vector) of type 'NULL'.
```

I then tried to install the package

> paprbag.

I got the error message:

> Biostrings is not installed and can not be installed given the R version.

```
> sessioninfo() R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I am helpless. I eventually tried to set a secondary repository option (Bioconductor) in the tools, since CRAN is the main setup.
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Does upgrading R to 3.5 solve this?

Comment: What happened when you tried to install `Biostrings`?

Comment: [this page](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) Says Biostrings requires R version >= 3.5 (look at the "depends" section of the table)

Comment: Thanks. I  uninstalled the version 3.4.4, but when I try to install the version 3.5 I always get the previous version 3.4.4. What should I do ?